# Debezium connector for SQL server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a confluent platform 7.1 installed by ansible I'm trying to run the Debezium 2.1 connector for SQL server using SASL_SSL authentication, when I ran the connector without authentication it works correctly without any issue but when I apply the authentication I get "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata"
i tried most of all published solutions but I could not solve the issue I'm sure that it is an authentication issue as I get in the logs that node are disconnected

```
  "name": "conn_XXX",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "confluent.topic.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm": "https",
    "provide.transaction.metadata": "true",
    "errors.retry.timeout": "1000",
    "errors.retry.delay.max.ms": "100",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "topic.prefix": "XXX",
    "database.names": "XXX",
    "database.hostname": "**.**.**.**",
    "database.port": "1433",
    "database.user": "XXX",
    "database.password": "XXX@123",
    "database.instance": "XXXXX",
    "poll.interval.ms": "100",
    "snapshot.mode": "initial",
    "snapshot.include.collection.list": "XXX",
    "snapshot.isolation.mode": "read_committed",
    "signal.data.collection": "XXX.dbo.XXX",
    "table.include.list": "dbo.XXX",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schemahistory_XXX",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "broker1.localhost.localdomain:9092,broker2.localhost.localdomain:9092,broker3.localhost.localdomain:9092",
    "sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
    "security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"kafka-connect\" password=\"kafka_connect-secret\";",
    "database.encrypt": "false",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "broker1.localhost.localdomain:9092,broker2.localhost.localdomain:9092,broker3.localhost.localdomain:9092",
    "database.history.consumer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
    "database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"kafka-connect\" password=\"kafka_connect-secret\";",
    "database.history.producer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
    "database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"kafka-connect\" password=\"kafka_connect-secret\";",
    "producer.override.sasl.jaas.config":"org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"kafka-connect\" password=\"kafka_connect-secret\";",
    "producer.override.sasl.mechanism":"PLAIN",
    "producer.override.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
    "consumer.override.sasl.jaas.config":"org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"kafka-connect\" password=\"kafka_connect-secret\";",
    "consumer.override.sasl.mechanism":"PLAIN",
    "consumer.override.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
    "connector.client.config.override.policy" : "ALL",
    "database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.location":"/var/ssl/private/kafka_connect.truststore.jks",
    "database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.password":"XXX",
    "database.history.consumer.ssl.truststore.location":"/var/ssl/private/kafka_connect.truststore.jks",
    "database.history.consumer.ssl.truststore.password":"XXX"


  }
}
```

and the anisble config tls part

```
 ssl_enabled: true
 sasl_protocol: plain
    sasl_plain_users:
      admin:
        principal: 'kafka'
        password: 'admin-secret'
      schema_registry:
        principal: 'schema-registry'
        password: 'schema_registry-secret'
      kafka_connect:
        principal: 'kafka-connect'
        password: 'kafka_connect-secret'
```

Comment: can you establish a connection on port 1433? try this command in cmd to see if you can `telnet sqladress 1433`

Comment: yes I can establish a connection on port 1433 via connect server, also I can run the connector successfully without sasl_ssl authentication, I mean when I remove all authentication security it works well but when I add it refuses.